# Back ground Image in CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Hello I am trying To add Back ground image in css file In Visual basic 2010 ASP.Net MVC
My Code is:

```
#page-container {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:url ('../Content/homepage.jpg');
    background:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

My Background picture doesn't appear. What may be the problem?

Comment: and question is??? or problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems:

1. There's a space between url and the first colon, so this:

   ```
   background-image:url ('../Content/homepage.jpg')
   ```

   should be this:

   ```
   background-image:url('../Content/homepage.jpg')
   ```
2. `background:cover` is not a correct css rule.

   I suppose what you want to do is `background-size:cover` instead. Be aware this is CSS3 so you might want to add the vendor prefixes:

   ```
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a networking tool such as Firebug in Firefox or Chrome's developer toolbar to see what URL is actually being generated by the CSS request for the background image.  You will see the request for the image (and will most likely be registering a 404) and compare that to what you expect it to be.

Most likely, you do not have the proper URL defined in the CSS, but without knowing your site structure it's hard to say.